# Why jquery is not working in head

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to put my code in `<head>` area because it takes some time to load the navigation menu in mobile devices. You can see the demo here: http://www.responsinator.com/?url=paison-templateify.blogspot.com.es%2F

I'm using `TinyNav.js` to Convert navigation to a select dropdown, and I'm adding a class in `<ul>` with jQuery here is my full code and currently its placed in footer area and its working, but it takes some time load.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menufy ul').addClass('zigla');
     $(".zigla").tinyNav();    
 });

 (function(a, i, g) {
     a.fn.tinyNav = function(j) {
         var b = a.extend({
             active: "selected",
             header: "",
             label: ""
         }, j);
         return this.each(function() {
             g;
             var h = a(this),
                 d = "tinynav"
             g, f = ".l_"
             d, e = a("<select/>").attr("id", d).addClass("tinynav "
                 d);
             if (h.is("ul,ol")) {
                 "" !== b.header && e.append(a("<option/>").text(b.header));
                 var c = "";
                 h.addClass("l_"
                     d).find("a").each(function() {
                     c = '<option value="'
                     a(this).attr("href")
                     '">';
                     var b;
                     for (b = 0; b < a(this).parents("ul, ol").length - 1; b) c = "- ";
                     c = a(this).text()
                     "</option>"
                 });
                 e.append(c);
                 b.header || e.find(":eq("
                     a(f " li").index(a(f " li."
                         b.active))
                     ")").attr("selected", !0);
                 e.change(function() {
                     i.location.href = a(this).val()
                 });
                 a(f).after(e);
                 b.label && e.before(a("<label/>").attr("for", d).addClass("tinynav_label "
                     d "_label").append(b.label))
             }
         })
     }
 })(jQuery, this, 0);
```

Why this code is not working in `<head>` area?

Comment: Don't post minified/obfuscated code on SO

Comment: i used http://jsbeautifier.org/ to clean the code :/

Comment: This bit here is totally invalid `return this.each(function() {
            g;
            var h = a(this),
                d = "tinynav"
            g, f = ".l_"
            d, e = a("<select/>").attr("id", d).addClass("tinynav "`

Comment: its not my code i'm using there script http://tinynav.viljamis.com/ if u want i will delete these lines from my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move

```
$('#menufy ul').addClass('zigla');
```

inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i did it and it working but the problem is its still takes time to load, you can the demo, is there any solution?

Comment: i did it, i moved the script.

Comment: yes, you can see the source,    view-source:http://paison-templateify.blogspot.com.es/

Comment: Ok. There is some script error coming in your js - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined - Please resolve that